# jQuery timout function interfering with toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox that I want to only stay checked for 7 seconds and then uncheck itself. I've put together the below code, but despite trying to clear the timeout, it seems to interfere with toggling if the user clicks several times on the toggle.

Can anyone help me find a cleaner way to do this that won't mis-behave if the users click too frequently?

```
$('input#foo').on('change', function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $('#box').addClass('splash').stop();
        $( "div.title" ).html( 'Hide thing' );
        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          if ( $('input#foo').is(':checked') ) {
            $('input#foo').prop('checked', false).change();
          }
        }, 7000);
    } 
    else {
        $('#box').removeClass('splash').stop();
        $( "div.title" ).html( 'Reveal thing' );

    }
  });
```

Comment: The *scope* for the timeout is only inside the on-change function.  Move `var timeout=` to before `$("input#foo").on("change...`.  Every time the on-change function is called, timeout will be null.  You can confirm this with a simple `console.log(timeout)` infront of cleartimeout

Answer (score 0):

Remove .change() from this line,and try it.
$('input#foo').prop('checked', false);

Comment: You might like to add a little more than just copy+paste the original code, if you don't want to *invite* downvotes...

Comment: Ah, apologies, it wasn't clear that that was the line you had changed.  Always add an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I've set it so the action only works 7 seconds after it is clicked, this should solve the mis-behaving

HTML

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">I will become unchecked in 7 seconds<br>
```

jQuery

```
$(".checkbox").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  }, 7000);
});
```

Fiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/8y8zu47p/2/